# Max gcc optimization for C extensions?

Tags: python, gcc, compiler-optimization

At least when GCC is used, Python compiles every C extension with mild speed optimization, that is, with the `-O2` flag.

What is the most portable way to make it use the most aggressive speed optimization available (for gcc `-O3`)?

I think there is a way to forcefully add `-O3` as compilation options for each extension (`extra_compile_args` attribute), but I am not keen in doing that as the underlying C compiler may not necessarily be gcc (it may understand or like `-O3`).

Comment: What do you mean with "python compiles"? You can easily create python modules with any compiler and any compilation setting you want as long as you link the right libraries and use the headers.

Comment: @Voo: I suspect he's talking about the usual way distutils builds Python extensions. Of course you can build whatever with whatever, but life is too short to waste it reimplementing buildsystems for other peoples' code.

Comment: `distutils.core.setup()` takes in the `ext_modules` parameter the list of C source files you want to see compiled as extensions. Of course, Python will delegate to the platform-specific compiler (like gcc), but it will also pass the compiler flags, including those controlling the optimization level.

Comment: @Matteo Shows how long I haven't actually created python modules and even then I had to create them for Windows too.

Comment: @Voo: unfortunately I had to get to know distutils a bit to fix some extension build (which also involved invoking SIP); I cannot recommend that stuff to anyone, I only got sadness from distutils.